# Select multiple SSRS tablix member properties?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

When I have a tablix with a row group and then static rows underneath the group, I have to click one by one on each static row and set the RepeatOnNewPage and KeepWithGroup properties on each tablix member.

Is there any way to select multiple static rows and set the tablix member properties all at once? Or am I stuck in this hell? :-)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are stuck.  At least, I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Comment: Most I've ever had to do were 2 or 3, doesn't take much time.

Comment: Open the `RDL` file and modify the properties in the `XML`. See if that gets you what you need.